# I cannot run example scenes with Manim

Tags: python-3.x, manim

So I have tried to run the example scene in Manim by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZltiKHFWmv8) tutorial, but it keeps giving me a `FileNotFoundError`, why is that?
What's annoying me is that the file that leads to the example scened **does** exist.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait it works. Basically install ffmpeg, unzip it, and make sure you add it to your *system variables* path, not the *user variable* path. After I did that the example worked fine.